ReactNative state of event.NativeEvent is always 4
I am trying to create a basic app with left and right swipe features for going to next or previous code. Most of the code is working except for this line:
event.nativeEvent.state === State.END

I have tried this with == as well but still fails as State.END is apparently 5 whereas left side returns 4.
So my swipe gestures do not work. I am able to see the translationX value in console.log. Here is the code base:
import { GestureHandlerRootView, PanGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import NewsCard from './NewsCard';
import { Dimensions, View, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native'; // Import Dimensions from react-native

interface NewsItem {
    title: string;
    image: string; // Assuming you have image URLs stored somewhere
    caption: string; // Source of the image
}

interface GestureEvent {
    nativeEvent: {
      state: State;
      translationX: number; // Assuming you're using translationX
    };
  }
  

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width; // Get screen width for swipe threshold

const newsData: NewsItem[] = [
    {
        title: 'Headline for News Item 1',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/200', // Replace with actual image URLs
        caption: 'Source: [Website Name]([website URL])', // Replace with actual source details
    },
    {
        title: 'Headline for News Item 2',
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/200', // Replace with actual image URLs
        caption: 'Source: [Another Website Name 2]([website URL])', // Replace with actual source details
    },
    // Add more news items here!
];

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    const onGestureEvent = (event: GestureEvent) => {
        //console.log(event.nativeEvent.state == State.END);
        if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
            const translationX = event.nativeEvent.translationX;
            console.log(translationX);
            const threshold = SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.3; // Set swipe threshold (e.g., 30% of screen width)

            if (translationX < -threshold) { // Check for left swipe
                setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => Math.min(prevIndex + 1, newsData.length - 1));
                console.log(currentIndex);
              } else if (translationX > threshold) { // Check for right swipe
                setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => Math.max(prevIndex - 1, 0));
                console.log(currentIndex);
              }
            
        }
    };

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}>
            <View>
                {newsData.map((item, index) => (
                    index === currentIndex && (
                        <NewsCard key={item.title} title={item.title} image={item.image} source={item.caption} />
                    )
                ))}
            </View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>

    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
});

export default App;


I am not sure what is it that I am doing incorrect here. Thank you in advance.
